# What is the minimum Adobe Reader version needed for PDFs generated by ColdFusion 8?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

I'm using ColdFusion 8 and creating PDFs dynamically with CFDOCUMENT. What is the minimum version of Adobe Reader needed to view these PDFs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open up the Document Properties of the generated PDF, you'll see:

> PDF Producer: iText 2.1.0 (by
>   lowagie.com)
>
> PDF Version: 1.4 (**Acrobat 5.x**)

I generate the PDF using CF9.0.1, but I guess it's the same for CF8.

Answer (score 1):

Or open the PDF in a text editor and look at the first line. It will say something like

%PDF-1.4

That is the version number (the second number is always 1 less than the version of Acrobat needed).

Don't save the file as you could break it!